# C# Application to upload file to SharePoint with MFA

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint

I am creating a Windows Form Application to insert data into MSSQL but also upload a file of user's choosing to SharePoint.
I tried to use the below code, however I have some serious problem due to Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) not being lifted for my service account. IT is very firm on this matter.

```
string SiteUrl = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite";
string DocumentLibrary = "Documents";
string FileName = @chkAttach1.Text.ToString();
string CustomerFolder = "Application Test";
string Username = "testuser";
string Password = "123";
foreach (char c in Password)
{ securePassword.AppendChar(c); }
var olCred = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, securePassword);
using (ClientContext cContext = new ClientContext(SiteUrl)) 
{
    cContext.Credentials = olCred;
    Web web = cContext.Web;
    FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
    byte[] FileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
    newFile.ContentStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(FileContent);
    newFile.Url = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName);
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List docLib = web.Lists.GetByTitle(DocumentLibrary);
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder uplFold = docLib.RootFolder.Folders.Add(CustomerFolder); 
    uplFold.Update();
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uplFile = uplFold.Files.Add(newFile);
    cContext.Load(docLib);
    cContext.Load(uplFile);
    cContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

So obviously the above is not working.
Speaking to a fellow from IT, he advised me to use API, but I have difficulties in finding a sample code online to upload a file to SharePoint using the user's current credentials.

Any advice?